# Why this powershell code works seperately in PS, but fails in a script?

Tags: powershell

I have this block in my deployment script which I am running on the build machine.
It should move files on staging machine from Installs folder to application folder.
**Before this block, there are several more actions successfuly executed with Invoke-Session**

```
write-host "Deploying" -foregroundcolor red -backgroundcolor yellow
invoke-command -session $s {
    Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Install\pre_master" | Copy-Item -Destination "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pre_master" -force -Recurse 
}
```

If I create a session manually in PS and paste this block, it works ok.

If I run the script, this step spams me with millions (for every file Im trying to move I suppose?)

> The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command
>   either because the command does not take pipeline in put or the input
>   and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take
>   pipeline input.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (0201-KS.xml:PSObject) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

So my question is : **Why this same block of code works in PS when executed manually. but doesnt work in script?**

Both machines have powershell 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm still don't know why, but you cannot use the pipeline when you run some cmdlets by using Remote session. You can first store the result of a cmdlet in a variable and then write a foreach loop to pipe the result of the cmdlet to another cmdlet.

For example, you can first store the result of a cmdlet in a variable and then writing a foreach loop to copy the files:

```
invoke-command -session $s {
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Install\pre_master"; Foreach($file in $files) { Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pre_master" -force Recurse} 
}
```

Comment: I have another script for different application that runs the same copy-item like in my provided sample, and it works.. The webserver is different though, I'm starting to think this might have corrupted windows/powershell...

Comment: And well, as I mentioned in question, if I execute the same invoker-command in PS manually, it works. Just doesnt work in a script